# Is multiprocessing.Manager.dict extract element will return the copy reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing moudle to build my project by using python 3.7 and i need to share some variables (such as requests.Session)

```
from multiprocessing import Manager

import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mag = Manager()
    md = mag.dict()

    md["session"] = requests.Session()
    print(md)
    print(md["session"])
    print(md["session"])

    origin_dict = dict()
    origin_dict["session"] = requests.Session()
    print(origin_dict)
    print(origin_dict["session"])
    print(origin_dict["session"])


[output]:
{'session': <requests.sessions.Session object at 0x000001A5CBEF8898>}
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x00000170415D54A8>
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x00000170415D5E48>
{'session': <requests.sessions.Session object at 0x0000017040FE5438>}
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x0000017040FE5438>
<requests.sessions.Session object at 0x0000017040FE5438>
```

The output of Manager.dict() result always got different pointer (seems like a shadow copy or deepcopy).

 The `origin_dict`(build-in dict) return expected result.